# Linking a user to another entity on create in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I am using the `FOS_user` bundle and when I create a user I want to link it to another Entity which is Company. I have tried to create a Listener using the following code:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event) {

}
```

This is working good and I have access to `$event` in the function. Now, I want to access the name of the company that the user added in the form. Also, I want to create a company and bind it to the new user, so something like this:

```
$company = new Entity\Company();
$company->setTitle($theInputFromTheForm);
$user->addCompany($company);
```

I don't know how to access the data of the form and save the company in the user. Is using a listener the proper way to do it?

Comment: Do you have a relation between `User` and `Company` in you model ? Can you please post the registration form ?

Answer (score 1):

The event `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` receive a `FormEvent` object. You can get the registration form in your listener using `$event->getForm()`

So in you case;

```
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
    $registrationForm = $event->getForm();
    $registrationFormData = registrationForm->getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a form type `CompanyType` that adds the title of my company. In my `RegistrationFormType` of my `UserBundle` I added a collection to this form type. I created a listener on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE` to add an empty company.

```
public function onRegistrationInitialize(UserEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $user->addCompany($company);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a clean solution. Is there something not clear in my answer ?

Comment: I've tried your solution but when I got the data from the form I didn't have the input of the title of the company. Company and User are 2 entities because I can have more than one company for the same user but when the user creates an account I want him to also enter the name of his business.

Comment: Can you please post the subscription form (update your question) ? So I can update my answer to show you how to get the title of the company and how connect it to `User`